# How to apply knn model on the test dataset after cross validation in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-caret

I am trying to solve the well-known problem named `Titanic- Machine Learning from Disaster`.

I want to apply `knn` to predict the `survived` from the test dataset. I also want to use `cross-validation` and then want to apply it to my test dataset.

The code structure is given below:

```
install.packages("caret")
library(caret)

knn_2_train <- knn_1_train # train dataset
knn_2_train$Survived <- train$Survived
Survived <- as.factor(train$Survived) # train labels

knn_2_test <- knn_1_test # test dataset

trControl <- trainControl(method  = "cv", number  = 5)

fit <- train(knn_2_train, Survived,
             method = "knn",
             tuneGrid   = expand.grid(k = 1:50),
             metric     = "Accuracy",
             trControl  = trControl
             )
```

Now, I am not sure how can I apply the `knn` model for the test dataset after the `cross-validation`.

Any kind of suggestion is appreciable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following;

```
test.df$predObs <- predict(
   object  = fit,
   newdata = test.df
)
```

This stores your predictions as `predObs` in your testset `test.df`, which you then can evaluate with various performance measures.

Good luck with you project!

**Note:** Remember to change `test.df` such that it corresponds to your test data. Let med know if it works for you!

Comment: Thanks, I got it. So, we can apply `predict` function!

Comment: Yeah it is pretty simple and straightforward really! Don't forget to upvote and accept the answer :-)

Also, check out https://topepo.github.io/caret/model-training-and-tuning.html
- It will cover all your needs!